# How to make a password field in the web setup project user interface?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment, custom-action, web-setup-project

In the web setup project(using VS) when creating a user interface, how can I create a password field ?? there isn't any property for making the input that written in the text field hidden(give star instead of showing the password)...

Note:
the type of the dialog that i'm using is a text box.

Thanks alot..

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is 3 years old I figured I would answer it, for future visitors - based on a tutorial I found (linked below)

First the bad news, this is not possible using the Visual Studio Setup Project (at least not in 2010 professional). However the good news is that you can

- Download **ORCA**
- Edit the textfield (under group 'control') and give it the property '**2097159**'

which will make every character you type a password character.

Taken from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6099/Set-a-password-textbox-for-Visual-Studio-NET-setup